# How to create a column in SQL Server Compact Edition using SQL Server Management Studio (2008) 

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms

I am trying to create an [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) edition in [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) 2008. I created the database and one table it. I also created one column in the table (using visual tools in SQL Server Management Studio) but I cannot create any other column.

Is there any possibility to create a column without using SQL commands (I can do this when I am working with a SQL Server database, by right clicking on the table and selecting design, but isn't this option available for SQL Server Compact?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled everything and reinstalled the latest version and now I can do this! Probably the versions were not correct or there was a problem with installation.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the table select Edit Table, add the new column at the bottom of the column list.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can not add a new column in this way. Only one column can be added in this way!

Comment: Which version of SQL managment studio do you have? which version of SQL CE? Mine are: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.0.2531.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.0.6002.18005
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.4211
Operating System      6.0.6002

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 SMS, SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2